# When to protect questions?

Tags: discussion

An older [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30445/does-shors-algorithm-imply-the-existence-of-the-multiverse) survived a vote to close, and had two answers as of couple of days ago. One by yours truly, and one by @CraigGidney.

Craig’s answer, focusing on the particulars of the question and proposing that there was a logical fallacy therein, was of course much more thorough and better than mine which focused instead on the textual considerations of the reference in the question.  While mine was voteless, Craig's answer rightfully engendered a net of four upvotes (as of a couple of days ago).

A recent answer by a new user (subtly?) disagrees with both of our answers, and was accepted by the OP.  Now Craig’s answer has picked up another downvote in the last couple of days.  ***I think the downvote came from this question being put on the front page after the most recent answer by the brand new user.***

I’ve protected questions when there are clear spam or junk or chatGPT answers; I’m a little close to this question as I’ve given an answer already and I also slightly disagree with much of the accepted answer - so I’m taking this to meta.  Accordingly do we have a policy on protection, and would it be an abuse of discretion to apply it to this case?

(A single downvote to a solid answer on a fluffy question doesn’t make or break the site, but consistency of policy should probably be strived for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the titular question, I don't think there's much more to say than what's said in [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/276202). The rationale of protecting questions is to avoid unwanted activity from low-rep users for questions that for one reason or the other attract it more than usual.

For the question at hand, I don't think protection is particularly necessary right now. Maybe if another answer from a similarly low-rep account pops out I might see it as more warranted, but as of now the situation still seems fine. I don't particularly agree with the new answer, but I don't think it warrants deletion or other action either. The real problem is that this kind of question is IMO just opinion-based, hence the lack of consensus reached in the answers. And for some reason, people also tend to feel quite strongly about these subjects, hence the higher number of downvotes. But then again, people who like engaging in interpretation discussions more than I do would probably disagree with such an assessment.